# Regex prefix only matches when in a look-behind assertion

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to parse a (seemingly very simple) piece of text like this.

```
some stuff
First name: John
Last name: Smith
more stuff
```

I want to capture the first and last name, so I tried a regex like this:

```
(?<=First name:\s*)(?<FirstName>\w+)(?<=\s*Last name:\s*)(?<LastName>\w+)
```

This fails to find a match. Each part (first name and last name) works individually, but they don't work together. Also, the following works

```
(?<=John\s*Last name:\s*)(?<LastName>\w+)
```

but when I move "John" out of the non-matching group...

```
John(?<=\s*Last name:\s*)(?<LastName>\w+)
```

... it doesn't match!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since look-behind assertions are zero-width (i.e. they don't consume any characters), the FirstName capture will match/capture whatever is after "First name:", in this case "John". After this first match, the position in the target string will be immediately after "John". But since the next part of the regex is another look-behind, the regex will look to see if what immediately precedes its current position matches your look-behind text, in this case "Last name:". Since it is actually preceded by "John", the whole regex fails and never even gets to "Smith".

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that I probably don't need the look-behind, because the following works:

```
First name:\s*(?<FirstName>\w+)\s*Last name:\s*(?<LastName>\w+)
```

Nevertheless, I'd be interested to know why it doesn't work with the look-behind for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure that newlines are matchable in whatever regex language you're using.

In Python, this means passing `re.DOTALL` to `re.compile()` or whatever `re` function you're using. In Perl, add `s` after the last slash.

Comment: I know this answer is ancient, but DOTALL/singleline mode wouldn't have any effect.  All it does is change the meaning of the dot, and there are no dots in this regex.